# Macbook Air display screen problem

Tags: macbook-pro, display

My macbook worked perfectly fine but then its battery ran out and when I recharged it, my screen looked like this, however, it functions perfectly fine. I cannot seem to figure out what the problem is because nothing happened to it. [image]

Comment: Have you tried restarting the Macbook?

Comment: Yes I have restarted it multiple times and also run the apple diagnostics test but it says that nothing is wrong with my macbook